# How to combine multiple inline style objects?

Tags: reactjs

In React you can clearly create an object and assign it as an inline style. i.e.. mentioned below.

```js
var divStyle = {
  color: 'white',
  backgroundImage: 'url(' + imgUrl + ')',
  WebkitTransition: 'all', // note the capital 'W' here
  msTransition: 'all' // 'ms' is the only lowercase vendor prefix
};

var divStyle2 = {fontSize: '18px'};

React.render(<div style={divStyle}>Hello World!</div>, mountNode);
```

How can I combine multiple objects and assign them together?

Answer (score 598):

If you're using React Native, you can use the array notation:

```js
<View style={[styles.base, styles.background]} />
```

Check out my detailed [blog post](https://blog.laska.io/combining-multiple-styles-in-react-native/) about this.

Comment: Sadly you can't do this in regular React.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer if you're using React-Native

Comment: You can slightly modify existing inline style by adding the style names/values. For example, `<View style={this.state.error == false ? styles.base : [styles.base, {backgroundColor: 'red'}]} />`

Comment: For two static styles, doing [`StyleSheet.compose()`](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/stylesheet#compose) outside the render function might be more efficient. It will produce a new static stylesheet that will only be sent over the bridge once. (This advice does not apply to styles which change at runtime, or which are inline instead of in a StyleSheet.)

Answer (score 355):

You can use the spread operator:

```js
 <button style={{...styles.panel.button,...styles.panel.backButton}}>Back</button
```

Comment: I get "Syntax error: Unexpected token", pointing at the first dot in the first spread operator.

Comment: @Izkata Are you doing this in react or react native, could you post your snippet

Comment: React, it was something like `<div style={{ ...LEGEND_STYLE.box_base, ...{ 'background': '#123456' } }} />`

Comment: I changed it anyway to use a helper function like `<div style={LEGEND_STYLE.box_gen('#123456')}` anyway, so it's not a big deal to me

Comment: This even works if the object has only one key-value pair, even though spread operators are only supposed to be valid for iterables! Can you explain why?
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator#Only_for_iterables

Comment: This is the best way to do merging.  `<View style={{...styles.listItem, height: this.itemHeight('15%')}}>` ...........

Comment: This is really missing a lot of details to be helpful to the original question.

Answer (score 72):

You can do this with `Object.assign()`.

In your example, you would do:

```js
ReactDOM.render(
    <div style={Object.assign(divStyle, divStyle2)}>
        Hello World!
    </div>,
    mountNode
);
```

That will merge the two styles. The second style will replace the first if there are matching properties.

As Brandon noted, you should use `Object.assign({}, divStyle, divStyle2)` if you want to reuse `divStyle` without the fontSize applied to it.

I like to use this to make components with default properties. For example, here's a little stateless component with a default `margin-right`:

```js
const DivWithDefaults = ({ style, children, ...otherProps }) =>
    <div style={Object.assign({ marginRight: "1.5em" }, style)} {...otherProps}>
        {children}
    </div>;
```

So we can render something like this:

```html
<DivWithDefaults>
    Some text.
</DivWithDefaults>
<DivWithDefaults className="someClass" style={{ width: "50%" }}>
    Some more text.
</DivWithDefaults>
<DivWithDefaults id="someID" style={{ marginRight: "10px", height: "20px" }}>
    Even more text.
</DivWithDefaults>
```

Which will give us the result:

```html
<div style="margin-right:1.5em;">Some text.</div>
<div style="margin-right:1.5em;width50%;" class="someClass">Some more text.</div>
<div style="margin-right:10px;height:20px;" id="someID">Even more text.</div>
```

Comment: this solution is potentially misusing `Object.assign()` in a way that would lead to some undesirable consequences. See [the answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37686582/5456001) a more reliable solution.

Comment: Your answer demonstrates a way to misuse Object.assign(). That might be useful information for some people, but it doesn't apply to my example. This example is not storing the default in an object, mutating it, then reusing the mutated object somewhere else.

Comment: disagree. you address two separate ways of using `Object.assign()` in your answer. the first, in the first few sentences, is an example of the misuse I identified (ie, if OP did what you advise in your first `code` block, he/she'd mutate `{divStyle}`). the second way--ie, wrapping it in a function as you have, will work, but the answer doesn't make it clear that you're _working around_ `Object.assign()`'s common  'gotcha'  wrt immutability (though personally  I think it's a little cumbersome to write a custom stateless function for every default component).

Comment: Oh, OK. That's true. If he wanted to reuse divStyle without applying the fontSize it'd need the empty object first. I'll update the answer.

Comment: Object.assign() is by far the most convenient way to achieve a concatenation :)

Answer (score 55):

Unlike React Native, we cannot pass array of styles in React, like

```
<View style={[style1, style2]} />
```

In React, we need to create the single object of styles before passing it to style property. Like:

```
const Header = (props) => {
  let baseStyle = {
    color: 'red',
  }

  let enhancedStyle = {
    fontSize: '38px'
  }

  return(
    <h1 style={{...baseStyle, ...enhancedStyle}}>{props.title}</h1>
  );
}
```

We have used ES6 [Spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator) to combine two styles. You can also use [Object.assign()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) as well for the same purpose.

This also works if you don't need to store your style in a var

```
<Segment style={{...segmentStyle, ...{height:'100%'}}}>
    Your content
</Segment>
```

Comment: Just to add to your last snippet, {{...segmentStyle, height:'100%'}} will also work.

Comment: This is actually the correct answer because the question was about styling of React, not React-native. Thanks pal.

Answer (score 33):

`Object.assign()` is an easy solution, but the (currently) [top answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34096086/5456001)'s usage of it — while just fine for making stateless components, will cause problems for the OP's desired objective of merging two `state` objects.

With two arguments, `Object.assign()` will actually mutate the first object in-place, affecting future instantiations.

Ex:

Consider two possible style configs for a box:

```
var styles =  {
  box: {backgroundColor: 'yellow', height: '100px', width: '200px'},
  boxA: {backgroundColor: 'blue'},
};
```

So we want all our boxes to have default 'box' styles, but want to overwrite some with a different color:

```
// this will be yellow
<div style={styles.box}></div>

// this will be blue
<div style={Object.assign(styles.box, styles.boxA)}></div>

// this SHOULD be yellow, but it's blue.
<div style={styles.box}></div>
```

Once `Object.assign()` executes, the 'styles.box' object is changed for good.

The solution is to pass an empty object to `Object.assign()`. In so doing, you're telling the method to produce a NEW object with the objects you pass it. Like so:

```
// this will be yellow
<div style={styles.box}></div>

// this will be blue
<div style={Object.assign({}, styles.box, styles.boxA)}></div>

// a beautiful yellow
<div style={styles.box}></div>
```

This notion of objects mutating in-place is critical for React, and proper use of `Object.assign()` is really helpful for using libraries like Redux.

Comment: Your example of how to misuse Object.assign is not a valid representation of how Object.assign is being used in the (currently) top answer.

Comment: thanks, made edits to reflect which aspect is (currently) a misuse

Comment: nice piece of code right there. Object.assign({}, this.state.showStartOverBtn ? {} : this.hidden ,this.btnStyle)} conditionals also work like a charm

Answer (score 27):

Array notaion is the best way of combining styles in react native.

This shows how to combine 2 Style objects,

```
<Text style={[styles.base, styles.background]} >Test </Text>
```

this shows how to combine Style object and property,

```
<Text style={[styles.base, {color: 'red'}]} >Test </Text>
```

This will work on any react native application.

Comment: The questions is for `React`, not `React Native`

Comment: You can use same for React also

Comment: React doesn't support array from the beginning and now it doesn't work anymore.

Comment: react not yet support combine style like this.

Comment: Do not understand why this rensponse have such upvote. Response off topic, here we talk about react, not react-native. Reactjs do not support what is say in this response

Answer (score 26):

```
    const style1 = {
        backgroundColor: "#2196F3", 
    }
    
    const style2 = {
        color: "white", 
    }

    const someComponent = () => {
        return <div style={{ ...style1, ...style2 }}>This has 2 separate styles</div> 
    }
```

Note the double curly brackets. The spread operator is your friend.

Comment: Should absolutely be accepted as the correct answer. Life saver!

Comment: I agree with @RobHern. This should be the accepted answer, which also allows adding other inline styles, like: style={{...styles.title, color: backgroundDark ? "#fff" : "#000"}}

Answer (score 22):

Actually, there is a formal way to combine and it is like below:

```
<View style={[style01, style02]} />
```

But, there is a *small issue*, if one of them is passed by the parent component and it was created by a combined formal way we have a big problem:

```
// The passing style02 from props: [parentStyle01, parentStyle02]

// Now:
<View style={[style01, [parentStyle01, parentStyle02]]} />
```

And this last line causes to have UI bug, surly, React Native cannot deal with a deep array inside an array. So I create my helper function:

```
import { StyleSheet } from 'react-native';

const styleJoiner = (...arg) => StyleSheet.flatten(arg);
```

By using my **`styleJoiner`** anywhere you can combine any type of style and combine styles. even `undefined` or other useless types don't cause to break the styling.

Answer (score 13):

You can also combine classes with inline styling like this:

```
<View style={[className, {paddingTop: 25}]}>
  <Text>Some Text</Text>
</View>
```

Comment: No, you cant do that. What is say here is Reactjs (note react native), not understand why have it such upvote

Answer (score 8):

Need to merge the properties in object.
For Example,

```
const boxStyle = {
  width : "50px",
  height : "50px"
};
const redBackground = {
  ...boxStyle,
  background: "red",
};
const blueBackground = {
  ...boxStyle,
  background: "blue",
}




 <div style={redBackground}></div>
 <div style={blueBackground}></div>
```

Comment: this was absolutely clever.

Answer (score 7):

I've found that this works best for me.  It overrides as expected.

```
return <View style={{...styles.local, ...styles.fromProps}} />
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use [compose](https://reactnative.dev/docs/stylesheet#compose)

```
 const styles = StyleSheet.create({
        divStyle :{
          color: 'white',
          backgroundImage: 'url(' + imgUrl + ')',
          WebkitTransition: 'all', // note the capital 'W' here
          msTransition: 'all' // 'ms' is the only lowercase vendor prefix
        },
        divStyle2 :{fontSize: '18px'}
    })
        
        React.render(<div style={StyleSheet.compose(styles.divStyle, styles.divStyle2)}>Hello World!</div>, mountNode);
```

OR

```
 React.render(<div style={[styles.divStyle, styles.divStyle2]}>Hello World!</div>, mountNode);
```

Comment: This was the solution that worked for me. The accepted solution did not work. On Expo 44 + ReactNative 0.64.3.

Comment: Stylesheet compose didn't work for me on react native. Passing styles as array worked brilliantly.

Answer (score 3):

To add multiple styles inline in react js, you can do like this

```
<div style={{...styles.cardBody,...{flex:2}}}>
```

Comment: using spread is operator is right approach , if you are in ES6. This is the right Answer. Also  a good example for combining styles classes and in-line style method

Answer (score 2):

For ones that looking this solution in React, If you want to use the spread operator inside style, you should use: babel-plugin-transform-object-rest-spread.

Install it by npm module and configure your .babelrc as such:

```
{
  "presets": ["env", "react"],
  "plugins": ["transform-object-rest-spread"]
}
```

Then you can use like...

```
const sizing = { width: 200, height: 200 }
 <div
   className="dragon-avatar-image-background"
   style={{ backgroundColor: blue, ...sizing }}
  />
```

More info: https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-transform-object-rest-spread/

Answer (score 1):

So basically I'm looking at this in the wrong way.  From what I see, this is not a React specific question, more of a JavaScript question in how do I combine two JavaScript objects together (without clobbering similarly named properties).

In this StackOverflow answer it explains it.  [How can I merge properties of two JavaScript objects dynamically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/171251/how-can-i-merge-properties-of-two-javascript-objects-dynamically)

In jQuery I can use the extend method.

Answer (score 1):

To Expand on what @PythonIsGreat said, I create a global function that will do it for me:

```
var css = function(){
    var args = $.merge([true, {}], Array.prototype.splice.call(arguments, 0));
    return $.extend.apply(null, args);
}
```

This deeply extends the objects into a new object and allows for a variable number of objects as parameters. This allows you to do something like this:

```
return(
<div style={css(styles.base, styles.first, styles.second,...)} ></div>
);

var styles = {
  base:{
    //whatever
  },
  first:{
    //whatever
  },
  second:{
    //whatever
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To take this one even further, you could create a [classnames](https://github.com/JedWatson/classnames)-like helper function:

```
const styleRules = (...rules) => {
  return rules.filter(Boolean).reduce((result, rule) => {
    return { ...result, ...rule };
  }, {});
};
```

And then use it conditionally in your components:

```
<div style={

  styleRules(
    divStyle,
    (window.innerWidth >= 768) && divStyleMd,
    (window.innerWidth < 768) && divStyleSm
  )

}>Hello World!</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Ways of inline styling:

```
<View style={[styles.red, {fontSize: 25}]}>
  <Text>Hello World</Text>
</View>

<View style={[styles.red, styles.blue]}>
  <Text>Hello World</Text>
</View>

  <View style={{fontSize:10,marginTop:10}}>
  <Text>Hello World</Text>
</View>
```

Comment: React doesn't support array from the beginning and now it doesn't work anymore.

Comment: the above comment is correct, this answer only works in React Native. it is possible to do something similar - <View style={{...styles.red, ...styles.blue}} /> like so, which React does support.

Answer (score 0):

I have built an module for this if you want to add styles based on a condition
like this:

```
multipleStyles(styles.icon, { [styles.iconRed]: true })
```

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-multiple-styles

Answer (score -5):

**To have multiple Inline styles in React.**

```
<div onClick={eleTemplate} style={{'width': '50%', textAlign: 'center'}}/>
```

Comment: In which way is this provide a multiple style?

Comment: The style accepts an object within curly braces, so you can have all your styles as a single object and assign it to one variable as below.

const combinedStyles = {'width': '50%', textAlign: 'center'}

<div onClick={eleTemplate} style={combinedStyles}/>