# How to add multiple line css object in one style tag react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, hover, mouseevent

Here I want to use two style in one line css. but i got error how i add two style object in style tag reactjs.
 here is my code:

```js
const style = {
    color:"black",
    fontSize:16,
    borderRadius:4,
    border: "1px solid grey",
    lineHeight: "28px",
    background: "white",
    padding: 3,
    margin:3
  }
  const hoverStyle = {
    color:"black",
    fontSize:16,
    borderRadius:4,
    border: "1px solid grey",
    lineHeight: "28px",
    background: "yellow",
    padding: 3,
    margin:3
  }
const highlightStyle = {
    color:"black",
    fontSize:16,
    border: "1px solid grey",
    background:"lightblue",
    borderRadius:4,
    lineHeight: "25px",
    padding: 3,
    margin:5
  }

 onHover(){ 
        console.log("mouse enter")  
        // this.setState({hover:!this.state.hover})       
    }
 
 
 <span id={this.props.atId} className = {this.props.classword}
  style={this.state.color_black ? style: highlightStyle,this.state.hover ? hoverStyle: ''}
  onClick={this.changeColor}
  onMouseEnter={() => {this.onHover()}}
  onMouseLeave={() => {this.onUnHover()}}
  //
>
  {item}
</span>
```

so what should i do add two style object in one line.
here i am using ternary operator. if my condition is true then print true part.
can anyone tell me how i add two style object.
help will be appreciated.
thank you

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29979324/how-to-combine-multiple-inline-style-objects

Comment: your effort is apreciated. but i want to write this in one style tag  look at this  {this.state.color_black ? style: highlightStyle (I GOT ERROR HERE),this.state.hover ? hoverStyle: ''} ............ here i am using two ternary operator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change on applying styles :

```
style={Object.assign({},
        this.state.color_black ? style : highlightStyle,
        this.state.hover && hoverStyle)}
        onMouseOver={this.hoverOn}
        onMouseLeave={this.hoverOff}
```

Working demo below :

[working demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-hmx4rv)

Answer (score 1):

`style={{...highlightStyle , ...hoverStyle}}`

This would display both styles from highlightStyle and hoverStyle.

The `...` operator is called spread operator in es6. [More on spread](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator)

Answer (score 0):

```
style={this.state.color_black ? highlightStyle : (this.state.hover ? hoverStyle: '')}
```

Comment: no no  dont change my code actually this.state.colorblack is operator and this.state.hover both are ddifferent. so tell i i add two ternary operator in one style tag react