# ReactJS dont take the css styles

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

**Technology :**

- ReactJS

**Todo :**

- When user chooses a number I need to change just the background
  style.
- The style is only maintained if **this.state.currentPage === number**, otherwise it does not show any style although I require the styles changing the background.

**Tried Case :**

```
 onClick={this.handleClick} style={this.state.currentPage === number ?
 styles.paginationButtons : [styles.paginationButtons,
 {backgroundColor:'blue'}]}>
```

Comment: please share all of your code

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to combine multiple inline style objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29979324/how-to-combine-multiple-inline-style-objects)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try updating your code so that you supply the dynamic styles to your component without the use of arrays.

You should be able to do so in this way:

```
style={ (this.state.currentPage === number ? styles.paginationButtons : { backgroundColor:'blue', ...styles.paginationButtons }) }
```