# How could i change multiple style tags of react Jss into minified stylesheet?

Tags: css, reactjs, webpack, next.js, css-in-js

I am using react with nextjs and react-jss for styling and trying to change multiple style tags of react Jss into one minified stylesheet.I tried toString() method of SheetRegistry class from react-jss but it is not working.

[multiple style tags being generated](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tq3nw.png)

Here is my _document.tsx

```js
class MyDocument extends Document {
  static async getInitialProps(ctx) {
    const registry = new SheetsRegistry();
    const generateId = createGenerateId();
    const originalRenderPage = ctx.renderPage;
    const sheet = new ServerStyleSheet();
    try {
      ctx.renderPage = () =>
        originalRenderPage({
          enhanceApp: (App) => (props) => (
            <JssProvider registry={registry} generateId={generateId}>
              {sheet.collectStyles(<App {...props} />)}
            </JssProvider>
          ),
        });
      const initialProps = await Document.getInitialProps(ctx);
      return {
        ...initialProps,
        styles: (
          <>
            {initialProps.styles}
            {sheet.getStyleElement()}
            <style id="server-side-styles">{registry.toString()}</style>
          </>
        ),
      };
    } finally {
      sheet.seal();
    }
  }
```

Here is my next.config.ts

```js
const withTM = require("next-transpile-modules")(["shared"]);
const withImages = require("next-images");
const nextSourceMaps = require("@zeit/next-source-maps");
const withCSS = require("@zeit/next-css");
const withSass = require("@zeit/next-sass");
const OptimizeCSSAssetsPlugin = require("optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin");
const path = require("path");
module.exports = withCSS(
  withSass(
    withImages(
      nextSourceMaps(
        withTM({
          distDir: "../../build",
          sassOptions: {
            includePaths: [path.join(__dirname, "styles")],
          },
          webpack: (config, { isServer }) => {
            config.optimization.minimizer = [];
            config.optimization.minimizer.push(new OptimizeCSSAssetsPlugin({}));
            if (!isServer) {
              config.resolve.alias["@sentry/node"] = "@sentry/browser";
            }
            return config;
          },
        })
      )
    )
  )
);
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to combine multiple inline style objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29979324/how-to-combine-multiple-inline-style-objects)

Comment: no, it does not solve my question.